# Show svg image from url in HTML

Tags: html, image, url, svg

I have an url to a svg file placed on some external server, eg: [user-online.svg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Breezeicons-actions-22-im-user-online.svg). I would like to display this image on my website. How can I do that? I tried attempt bellow, but it doesn't work and show just [image: broken image].

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Breezeicons-actions-22-im-user-online.svg">
```

Comment: And using the file from your own server? I presume wikimedia prevents hijacking files, looks like its send as text

Comment: you will most likely have to use a php script to read the data and encode it

Comment: that file is served as text/plain rather than image/svg+xml so it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

This is how it's supposed to be done:

```html
<svg width="90" height="90">       
     <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Breezeicons-actions-22-im-user-online.svg" width="90" height="90"/>    
</svg>
```